# How can I run a diagnostic install on a Mac dmg?

Tags: macos, mac, installation, diagnostic

I know how to do this in Windows, example in the commandline:

> msiexec /i gtk-sharp-2.12.22.msi /l*v c:\Users\anyuser\Documents\gtk-sharp-msi.log

(Documentation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_SetLogging)

But I can't seem to find an equivalent command on Mac to diagnose why an install might not be working there. Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web page explaining [“Check what the OS X installer is doing”](http://www.macissues.com/2014/04/08/check-what-the-os-x-installer-is-doing/) might suffice; it shows how to view the logs directly from the installer.

With the installer in focus, press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or select “Window -> Installer Log” to open the installer log menu. I didn’t find a way to do it through the command line, which if possible (and similar to windows), might offer more detailed / verbose diagnostic info; perhaps.